# What are the math topics involved in FRM 1

Tags: risk-management

Is there a way to get the math curriculum for FRM level 1 without purchasing the Exam? I wish to take a look at the math topics and see if I have any chance of cracking it. But  I could not find an online resource that lists the math topics required for FRM 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below. You can find out more [here at the GARP website](http://www.garp.org/media/1216429/frm_study_guide_2014-web.pdf). You may need to register, but it's free. Download the study guide. The bullets below are from it.

- Discrete and continuous probability distributions
- Population and sample statistics
- Statistical inference and hypothesis testing
- Estimating the parameters of distributions
- Graphical representation of statistical relationships
- Linear regression with single and multiple regressors
- The Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method
- Interpreting and using regression coefficients, the t-statistic, and
  other output
- Hypothesis testing and confidence intervals
- Heteroskedasticity and multicollinearity
- Simulation methods
- Estimating correlation and volatility using EWMA and GARCH models
- Volatility term structures

Comment: Thanks. Matrix algebra is not explicitly mentioned...but I suppose good knowledge of matrix algebra is expected anyway?

Comment: These topics are covered in curriculum, detailed knowledge going in isn't required, but would definitely be beneficial. Having sat for, and passed part 1 (in 2013), I can say that a good grasp of basic statistics and basic algebra is a minimum requirement.